# How do I format OpenApi in swagger-php so that the swagger-ui shows a form instead of an array?

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-php

I'm on a Laravel build, and updating notations for all my API controller methods from @SWG to @OA.  When I hit 'try it out' in the swagger-ui on a create method, I'm able to get it to show (and accept) an editable array of parameters and values (the latter being the examples I coded in), but I'd much rather get a form of the given parameters instead, to be sent in the body, not the query.  I was able to do it in the older version by adding parameters and setting the 'in' parameter to 'body', but the documentation says I have to use requestBody now.  Not terribly pleased with the results...functional, but not optimal.

Here's an example of a requestBody I'm using currently:

```
/**
 *
 * @OA\RequestBody(
 *     request="Answer",
 *     description="Answer object that needs to be added.",
 *     required=true,
 *     @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/schemas/Answer")
 * )
 */
```

I suspect I need to do something with @mediaType, but when I try it, with a list of parameters, it doesn't give me anything 8(

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was conflating the requestBody with the response...thought I'd need to send in json to get back json.  Nope lol  Just needed to send it with a form-data mediaType.

Here's what I ended up with, in case it helps someone:

```
/**
 *
 *  @OA\RequestBody(
 *      request="Answer",
 *      description="Answer object that needs to be added.",
 *      required=true,
 *      @OA\MediaType(
 *          mediaType="multipart/form-data",
 *          @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/Answer")
 *      )
 *  )
 */
```